# Мониторинг выполнения скрипта

Tags: php, мониторинг

Здравствуйте. Сайт работает на php + mysql.
Долго грузятся страницы, именно из-за соединения с базой (стили, js и графику убрал).

Вопрос. Каким инструментом можно проверить какой запрос занимает больше всего времени?

Comment: Профилировщиком, можно наколеночным

Comment: @vp_arth а что за он? можно ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой метод, это использовать `EXPLAIN`  при `SELECT`  запросах, в результате вы получите информацию при данном запросе какие ресурсы используются и какое время уходит на выполнение.
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM your_table`
Можете почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211022/)

Думаю у вас в основном могут быть проблемы с `Index`, проблемы с которыми очень  часто встречаеться разработчики. Правильно используя ключи вы сможете получить прирост скорости, пример можете прочитать [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)